# why is my list not printing all the elements? is the list programmed wrong?

Tags: python, list, statistics

```
import statistics

def main():
    Start() 
    lst = Read_Temperatures() 
    Celsius = Convert_Celsius(lst) 
    Calculate_mean(lst,Celsius)
    #Display Results
    Display_Results(lst,Celsius)

def Start():
    print("\t")
    print("\t")
    print("\t")

def Read_Temperatures():
    lst = [5]
    for i in range(5):
         print("\tEnter Temp", end ='')
         answers = input()
    lst.append(answers)
    lst = [float (i) for i in lst]
    return lst

def Convert_Celsius(lst):
    Celsius = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        lst[i] = (lst[i]-32)/1.8
    Celsius = lst.copy()
    return Celsius

def Calculate_mean(lst,Celsius):
    mediaf = statistics.mean(lst)
    mediac = statistics.mean(Celsius)

    return mediaf,mediac
#===========================================

def Display_Results(lst,Celsius) :
    for i in lst:
        print(lst)

#===================================================================
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not saving the results of `Calculate_mean()` or printing the means. I've added code to do that.
2. `Convert_Celsius()` is modifying `lst` in place before making a copy of it. But the damage has already been done. You should just push the celsius values onto the `Celsius array, or use a list comprehension.
3. `Display_Results()` is only printing one of the lists.

```
import statistics

def main():
    Start() 
    lst = Read_Temperatures() 
    Celsius = Convert_Celsius(lst) 
    mediaf, mediac = Calculate_mean(lst,Celsius)
    #Display Results
    Display_Results(lst,Celsius, mediaf, mediac)

def Start():
    print("\t")
    print("\t")
    print("\t")

def Read_Temperatures():
    lst = [5]
    for i in range(5):
         print("\tEnter Temp", end ='')
         answers = input()
    lst.append(answers)
    lst = [float (i) for i in lst]
    return lst

def Convert_Celsius(lst):
    Celsius = [(f-32)/1.8 for f in lst]
    return Celsius

def Calculate_mean(lst,Celsius):
    mediaf = statistics.mean(lst)
    mediac = statistics.mean(Celsius)

    return mediaf,mediac
#===========================================

def Display_Results(lst,Celsius, mediaf, mediac):
    for f, c in zip(lst, Celsius):
        print(f, c)
    print("Means:", mediaf, medac)

#===================================================================
main()
```